# Python3.9 pandas save pivotted data frame as a proper csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pivot

I have this csv:

```
Label,Visits,Actions,Maximum actions in one visit,Total time spent by visitors (in seconds),Bounces,Visits with Conversions,Unique visitors (daily sum),Users (daily sum),Metadata: segment,Metadata: referrer_type, cmpgn_group2, cmpgn_group3
Search Engines,4386,5836,15,351989,3547,0,4098,0,referrerType==search,2, name_1, 08-09
Campaigns,2618,3007,20,68609,2385,0,2579,0,referrerType==campaign,6, name_1, 08-09
Direct Entry,2266,3056,21,211456,1833,0,1943,0,referrerType==direct,1, name_1, 08-09
Websites,1097,2002,15,149385,722,0,987,0,referrerType==website,3, name_1, 08-09
Social Networks,691,787,8,18003,623,0,655,0,referrerType==social,7, name_1, 08-09
Search Engines,4045,10889,78,454772,2124,0,3860,0,referrerType==search,2, name_2, 08-09
Direct Entry,1046,3246,111,127677,572,0,943,0,referrerType==direct,1, name_2, 08-09
Websites,139,498,43,21249,61,0,133,0,referrerType==website,3, name_2, 08-09
Social Networks,81,176,16,6667,54,0,77,0,referrerType==social,7, name_2, 08-09
Direct Entry,6752,20806,60,994228,2994,0,5956,0,referrerType==direct,1, name_3, 08-09
Search Engines,3266,14436,50,920652,805,0,2982,0,referrerType==search,2, name_3, 08-09
Websites,250,1413,30,87955,51,0,233,0,referrerType==website,3, name_3, 08-09
Campaigns,27,165,28,8428,3,0,27,0,referrerType==campaign,6, name_3, 08-09
Social Networks,12,31,11,3900,4,0,12,0,referrerType==social,7, name_3, 08-09
```

What I want to do is to aggregate (sum) the `Visits` column with `Label` as columns and  `cmpgn_group2` as rows, so the final result would look like this:

```
cmpgn_group2,Campaigns,Direct Entry,Search Engines,Social Networks,Websites                                                               
name_1,2618.0,2266.0,4386.0,691.0,1097.0
name_2,,1046.0,4045.0,81.0,139.0
name_3,27.0,6752.0,3266.0,12.0,250.0
```

However when I just print my data frame, I get this:

```py
                 Visits                                                     
Label         Campaigns Direct Entry Search Engines Social Networks Websites
 cmpgn_group2                                                               
 name_1          2618.0       2266.0         4386.0           691.0   1097.0
 name_2             NaN       1046.0         4045.0            81.0    139.0
 name_3            27.0       6752.0         3266.0            12.0    250.0
```

Which is good inside of my Jupyter notebook for readability, however when I use the `to_csv()` function, I would like to have a proper csv (looking like the one I showed above), unfortunately what I get is this:

```
,Visits,Visits,Visits,Visits,Visits
Label,Campaigns,Direct Entry,Search Engines,Social Networks,Websites
 cmpgn_group2,,,,,
 name_1,2618.0,2266.0,4386.0,691.0,1097.0
 name_2,,1046.0,4045.0,81.0,139.0
 name_3,27.0,6752.0,3266.0,12.0,250.0
```

Which is not a proper csv from my point of view and I cant use it in my workflow.

This is my code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('channels_26_Oct_2020.csv')
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Visits'], columns=['Label'], index=' cmpgn_group2', aggfunc=np.sum)
print(df2)
df2.to_csv('channels_26_Oct_2020_2.csv')
```

What is the correct approach to this? How can I create a proper csv?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `pivot_table` creates multi-index DataFrames. You can collapse them into a single index like this:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Visits'], columns=['Label'], index=' cmpgn_group2', aggfunc=np.sum)
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)
df2.to_csv('ex1.csv')
```

Ouput CSV file:

```
 cmpgn_group2,Visits_Campaigns,Visits_Direct Entry,Visits_Search Engines,Visits_Social Networks,Visits_Websites
 name_1,2618.0,2266.0,4386.0,691.0,1097.0
 name_2,,1046.0,4045.0,81.0,139.0
 name_3,27.0,6752.0,3266.0,12.0,250.0
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know map() exists in pandas (feeling kind of embarrassed right now), I will experiment with it. Does it also work for multiple indexes?

Comment: `df2.columns` looks like this:
`MultiIndex([('Visits',       'Campaigns'),
            ('Visits',    'Direct Entry'),
            ('Visits',  'Search Engines'),
            ('Visits', 'Social Networks'),
            ('Visits',        'Websites')],
           names=[None, 'Label'])`
That's why we can use `map` to combine is into one

Comment: Ok, I now understand, but this works only if all columns are string from my experiments if I am joining strings and ints I have to use something a little bit different. Anyways, thank you very much.